# Sitemesh 2 is not decorating my JSPs

Tags: java, jsp, jersey, glassfish, sitemesh

I'm trying to use Sitemesh 2.4.2 to decorate some JSPs with a navbar, and also to extract my CSS references into this decorator. However, I can't make it work: depending on how I set up the pattern in my `decorators.xml`, I'm either getting only the base JSP with no decorator, or the decorator (this is, the content of the `<head>` tag, and the `<navbar>` I'm adding at the beginning of my `<body>` tag) with no content from the base JSP.
My application is using Glassfish 4 as the application server, hence using Jersey 2. Since I'm using JSPs, I'm using Jersey as a filter.

This is my `web.xml` (I'm not entirely sure if I need this FORWARD dispatcher)

```
<web-app version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
        http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">

  <filter>
    <filter-name>SiteMeshFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>com.opensymphony.sitemesh.webapp.SiteMeshFilter</filter-class>
  </filter>
  <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>SiteMeshFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
  </filter-mapping>

  <filter>
    <filter-name>jersey</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</filter-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>jersey.config.servlet.filter.forwardOn404</param-name>
      <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>javax.ws.rs.Application</param-name>
      <param-value>com.xxx.jersey2.config.CustomResourceConfig</param-value>
    </init-param>
  </filter>

  <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>jersey</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </filter-mapping>

</web-app>
```

My `decorators.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<decorators defaultdir="/WEB-INF/decorators">
<decorator name="main" page="my_navbar.jsp">
  <!--<pattern>/jsp/*</pattern>-->
  <pattern>/*</pattern>
</decorator>
</decorators>
```

Here, if I change the pattern to `<pattern>/jsp/*</pattern>`, then the decorator wouldn't be included at all — I would get just the base JSP.
By setting the pattern to `<pattern>/*</pattern>`, I'm getting *only the decorator*, this is, I'm getting only the content of `my_navbar.jsp`. Also, Sitemesh's tags on it, like `<decorator:body />`, won't be rendered at all, and they would appear in the resulting webpage source code that can be seen from the browser.

This is the JSP that's going to be decorated, `my_navbar.jsp`

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Sandbox application</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../../js/jquery-1.12.4.min.js">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../../css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../../js/bootstrap.min.js">
    <decorator:head />
</head>
<body>

<nav class="navbar navbar-light bg-faded">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="/sample-jersey2/">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="/sample-jersey2/movies/list/">Movies</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="/sample-jersey2/genres/list/">Genres</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>

<decorator:body />

</body>
</html>
```

And finally, one of the JSPs I'm trying to get decorated with my navbar and styles

```
<%@page contentType="text/html"%>
<%@page pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>

<h2>Listing Movies</h2>
    <table class="table table-striped">
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Starring</th>
            <th>Genre</th>
        </tr>
        <c:forEach var="item" items="${it.movies}">
            <tr>
                <td>${item.name}</td>
                <td>${item.starring}</td>
                <td>${item.genre}</td>
            </tr>
        </c:forEach>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Any ideas on this would be greatly appreciated.
Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was missing this line in my `my_navbar.jsp` file:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="decorator" uri="http://www.opensymphony.com/sitemesh/decorator" %>
```

Now it works properly.